# What is the most efficient way of adding body of text from word document to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add a EULA to our web app, the EULA was drafted by our legal and its a large body of text in a word document.

I want to show this on login in form of a modal if user clicks a link "End user license agreement"

options:

1. copy all the text and paste it in react modal component?
2. keep word document in source folder and on button click, read the file and put contents in modal?
3. better way of doing this?

edit: I want to know programmatically. Something I can easily scale in future/maintain

Comment: Efficient can mean a number of things, e.g. the most time efficient thing for you as a developer is probably not the most programatically efficient thing, nor the most maintainable. What sort of efficiency do you mean?

Comment: sorry meant Programatically ill edit the main question.

Comment: Bearing in mind that this most likely will need some kind of formatting, personally, i'd store it in a database, and then fetch it on click.
Then giving legal an endpoint with a WYSIWYG editor. This way legal can change it whenever they like - and also do the formatting themself

Comment: @Filtenborg the current document from legal is in word format. Would I need to extract the contents manually and put it in a db? If i am using aws, wondering what is programmatically efficient way of storing it in db